# Best way to store/filter dynamic tables with over 1 milion records

Tags: mongodb, data-structures

My case is to store 1 milion rows, every row contains a map (Map<String, Object>).
We should be able to filter rows by map elements as quickly as possible.

What would be the best way for its storage?
Currently I'm trying mongoDB but I'm open to any other solutions.

Best regards and thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `Map<String, Object>` - is it a Java `Map` collection? If possible include sample data.

Comment: Yes, it is just a flat Map with Strings, numbers and booleans